# Workflow content missing when viewed from another PC

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I created few workflows in my company site using SharePoint designer 2013 in my office computer.(My company is using SharePoint Online 2013).I saved the workflows and published them in the site.They were working perfectly.

Then i went home and opened the same site from the SharePoint designer 2013 in my personal computer

I could open the site and open the workflows.

But all the `content/steps/settings` of the workflows were missing.

Is workflow `content/steps` local to the SharePoint designer? If so is there a way to copy those `Content/Settings` to my personal computer also?

Or else is there something wrong with the SharePoint designer installed in my personal computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not re-publish with bad content and the workflow still works on O365 then your workflow is ok and the activities are there.

Once you save/publish your workflows they are stored in the content database with the site.  Nothing is stored local on your machine.  There may be an issue with your second instance of Designer or your connection however.  When you first open a site in SharePoint designer it will download that workflow activities available for that site.  If that doesn't happen, then you wont see those in a workflow.

Comment: Once i re-install Sharepoint designer i could see the workflows in the server properly.